# How do I know that I'm vulnerable to the: " Coordinated Website Compromise Campaigns Continue to Plague Internet "

Tags: known-vulnerabilities

> http://blogs.cisco.com/security/mass-compromise-of-the-obsolete/

and:

> All Redhat/CentOS versions plus nearly 100% of linux-based routers run
>   2.6

Since the article is extremely uninformative..

**Q:** How do I know that I'm vulnerable or not? ex.: If I have an OpenWRT router, or Redhat 5?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there isn't enough public information to know which systems are vulnerable. The Cisco blog you linked to appears to be the primary source for this news (other sites [have since picked it up](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/03/ancient-linux-servers-the-blighted-slum-houses-of-the-internet/), but add nothing), and it does have any concrete information on the infection vector.

The Cisco blog now includes the following edit (emphasis mine):

> The observation of affected hosts running Linux kernel 2.6 is
>   **anecdotal and in no way reflects a universal condition among all of
>   the compromised websites**. Accordingly, we have adjusted the title for
>   clarity. **We have not identified the initial exploit vector for the
>   stage zero URIs**. It was not our intention to conflate our anecdotal
>   observations with the technical facts provided in the listed URIs or
>   other demonstrable data, and the below strike through annotations
>   reflect that. We also want to thank the community for the timely
>   feedback.

Answer (score 1):

the article is ... well ...  i wouldnt buy anything from a company with such a low level of knowlegde.

> How do I know that I'm vulnerable or not?

answer in the blog: "We haven’t identified the initial attack vector. "

my guess:

- infected admin-workstations
- sniffed ftp-passwords (yes, even in 2014)
- outdated plesk/cpanel - installations
- outdated webapps

again:

> How do I know that I'm vulnerable or not?

let someone with some more understanding judge about this; i dont know what you mean by "ex.: If I have an OpenWRT router, or Redhat 5?"

Comment: my suspicion is that OP was asking about what artifacts, behaviors or conditions should s/he be looking for to identify whether or not their system is infected...